# VSCode not respecting webpack's resolve aliases when importing Sass files

Tags: webpack, sass, visual-studio-code

I have the following in my `webpack.config.app.js`:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    "modules": path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../css/common/modules'),
  }
}
```

and I'm importing files in my `*.scss` like so:

```
@import "~modules/variables";
```

Everything builds just fine, but VSCode doesn't recognize the path when I try to `ctrl+click` on it to get to the source. Is there any way to get VSCode to resolve this import to the right path?

---

### What I've tried

I tried adding the path to `tsconfig.json` based on the answers to similar problems, but it seemed to have no effect.

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "./src",
  "paths": {
    "~modules/*": ["../../../css/common/modules"]
  },
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, have you sorted this out?

Comment: @dennisbot Unfortunately I never found a solution to this and have given up. We have since migrated to using Emotion instead which doesn't have this problem